# No Source Available..Browse to find source

Tags: vb.net

when i execute vb.net code..I got below error.

No Source Available.There is no source code available for the current location.
Browse to find source.

How to solve this error?

I can't browse any source..its disabled..

here is the code:

Private Sub ButtonProductAdvertisingAPIItemLookup_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonProductAdvertisingAPIItemLookup.Click
        sender.Enabled = False

```
    'Product Advertising API, ItemLookup: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ItemLookup.html

    Dim ItemId(9) As String

    ItemId(0) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn1.Text)
    ItemId(1) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn2.Text)
    ItemId(2) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn3.Text)
    ItemId(3) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn4.Text)
    ItemId(4) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn5.Text)
    ItemId(5) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn6.Text)
    ItemId(6) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn7.Text)
    ItemId(7) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn8.Text)
    ItemId(8) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn9.Text)
    ItemId(9) = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxisbn10.Text)

    ' For Each ItemId As String In ItemIds()


    Dim i As Integer = 0
    System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(ItemIds, Sub(ItemIds)


                                                         My.Settings.ItemId = ItemIds

                                                         Dim MyREST As New SprightlySoftAWS.REST

                                                         Dim RequestURL(i) As String

                                                         RequestURL(i) = "https://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemLookup&Version=2011-08-01"
                                                         'RequestURL(i) = "http://isbndb.com/api/books.xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemLookup&Version=2011-08-01"

                                                         RequestURL(i) += "&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJCA3UI55HFYAXQ6Q&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&Timestamp=" & Uri.EscapeDataString(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:ss.fff\Z"))
                                                         RequestURL(i) += "&AssociateTag=AKIAJCA3UI55HFYAXQ6Q"
                                                         RequestURL(i) += "&ResponseGroup=" & System.Uri.EscapeDataString("ItemAttributes,Large,OfferSummary,Offers,VariationSummary,VariationImages, Reviews")
                                                         RequestURL(i) += "&ItemId=" & System.Uri.EscapeDataString(ItemIds)
                                                         RequestURL(i) += "&IdType=ISBN"
                                                         RequestURL(i) += "&SearchIndex=Books"

                                                         Dim RequestMethod As String
                                                         RequestMethod = "GET"

                                                         Dim SignatureValue As String
                                                         SignatureValue = MyREST.GetSignatureVersion2Value(RequestURL(i), RequestMethod, "", "8igixqKPKWTcsWxgWdqz+rVofSWIPcC3WynhEl1r")

                                                         RequestURL(i) += "&Signature=" & System.Uri.EscapeDataString(SignatureValue)

                                                         Dim RetBool As Boolean
                                                         RetBool = MyREST.MakeRequest(RequestURL(i), RequestMethod, Nothing)

                                                         Debug.Print("")
                                                         Debug.Print(MyREST.LogData)
                                                         Debug.Print("")

                                                         Dim Y As Integer
                                                         Dim ResponseMessage As String = ""
                                                         ResponseMessage = ResponseMessage.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")


                                                         'Dim strb As String = ResponseMessage.TrimEnd

                                                         If RetBool = True Then
                                                             Dim MyXmlDocument As System.Xml.XmlDocument
                                                             Dim MyXmlNamespaceManager As System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager
                                                             Dim MyXmlNode As System.Xml.XmlNode
                                                             Dim MyXmlNodeList As System.Xml.XmlNodeList

                                                             MyXmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument
                                                             MyXmlDocument.LoadXml(MyREST.ResponseString)

                                                             MyXmlNamespaceManager = New System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(MyXmlDocument.NameTable)
                                                             MyXmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("amz", "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")

                                                             MyXmlNodeList = MyXmlDocument.SelectNodes("amz:ItemLookupResponse/amz:Items/amz:Item", MyXmlNamespaceManager)

                                                             If MyXmlNodeList.Count = 0 Then
                                                                 ResponseMessage = "Item not found."
                                                             Else

                                                                 For Each ItemXmlNode As System.Xml.XmlNode In MyXmlNodeList


                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:ASIN", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "Details of " & MyXmlNode.InnerText
                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf


                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:ItemAttributes/amz:ISBN", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "ISBN" & MyXmlNode.InnerText
                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     ' MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:ASIN", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     'ResponseMessage+=Condition "New" 



                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:ItemAttributes/amz:Title", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "Title = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText.Replace(vbCrLf, "")

                                                                     'ResponseMessage = ResponseMessage.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")

                                                                     ' ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:MediumImage/amz:URL", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "Image = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText

                                                                     'ResponseMessage += Replace(ResponseMessage, vbCrLf, "")

                                                                     'ResponseMessage += vbCr
                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf


                                                                     MyXmlNodeList = ItemXmlNode.SelectNodes("amz:ItemAttributes/amz:Author", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     If IsNothing(MyXmlNodeList) = False Then
                                                                         ResponseMessage += "Author = "
                                                                         For Each MyXmlNode In MyXmlNodeList
                                                                             ResponseMessage += MyXmlNode.InnerText & ", "
                                                                         Next
                                                                     End If

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:ItemAttributes/amz:ListPrice/amz:FormattedPrice", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "ListPrice = "
                                                                     If IsNothing(MyXmlNode) = False Then
                                                                         ResponseMessage += MyXmlNode.InnerText
                                                                     End If

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:Offers/amz:Offer/amz:OfferAttributes/amz:Condition", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "Condition = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText

                                                                     'ResponseMessage += "Condition= New "  

                                                                     ' MessageBox.Show("Condition=new")

                                                                     'MessageBox("Condition=New")

                                                                     'MsgBoxResult("condition=New")

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:Offers/amz:TotalOffers", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "TotalOffers = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:OfferSummary/amz:TotalNew", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "TotalNew = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNodeList = ItemXmlNode.SelectNodes("amz:OfferSummary/amz:LowestNewPrice/amz:FormattedPrice", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "LowestNewPrice = "
                                                                     Y = 0
                                                                     For Each MyXmlNode In MyXmlNodeList
                                                                         If Y < 25 Then
                                                                             ResponseMessage += "" & MyXmlNode.InnerText & "  "
                                                                         End If
                                                                     Next

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:OfferSummary/amz:TotalUsed", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "TotalUsed = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:OfferSummary/amz:LowestUsedPrice/amz:FormattedPrice", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     ResponseMessage += "LowestUsedPrice = "
                                                                     If IsNothing(MyXmlNode) = False Then
                                                                         ResponseMessage += "" & MyXmlNode.InnerText
                                                                     Else
                                                                         ResponseMessage += "0"
                                                                     End If

                                                                     ResponseMessage += vbCrLf

                                                                     'MyXmlNode = ItemXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("amz:SalesRank", MyXmlNamespaceManager)
                                                                     'ResponseMessage += "SalesRank = " & MyXmlNode.InnerText

                                                                     'ResponseMessage += vbCrLf
                                                                 Next
                                                             End If

                                                             DialogOutput.Text = "Success"
                                                             DialogOutput.TextBoxOutput.Text += vbCrLf & ResponseMessage & vbCrLf
                                                             'DialogOutput.TextBoxOutput.Text += vbCrLf & ResponseMessage


                                                         Else
                                                             ResponseMessage = FormatLogData(MyREST.RequestURL, MyREST.RequestMethod, MyREST.RequestHeaders, MyREST.ResponseStatusCode, MyREST.ResponseStatusDescription, MyREST.ResponseHeaders, MyREST.ResponseStringFormatted, MyREST.ErrorNumber, MyREST.ErrorDescription)

                                                             DialogOutput.Text = "Error"
                                                             DialogOutput.TextBoxOutput.Text = ResponseMessage
                                                             DialogOutput.ShowDialog(Me)
                                                             DialogOutput.Dispose()
                                                         End If

                                                         i = i + 1
                                                     End Sub)
    'Next

    DialogOutput.ShowDialog(Me)
    ClearTextBox(Me)
    sender.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

when i run these code..i got "No source available" Error.Please anyone check the code and give solution.

Comment: Please describe your problem further.  It's currently not clear what exactly you are describing.  Perhaps if you gave the steps you follow to get to the error, that would help.  What do you mean that browsing to the source is disabled?

Comment: I get this when .NET development server shuts down.  Re-running the application usually restarts the development server and fixes the issue.

Comment: Please check above code..

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild the solution before you run it for the first time. This used to happen to me a lot.

Comment: I tried to rebuild the solution..but again i got the same error "No source available"..